# How do I add text to a specific line in a text file in visual basic?

Tags: vb.net, vb.net-2010

I am trying to create a program for an a level project using visual studio 2010 or 2017 at home, and am using a console application. What I need it to do is to create a text file with the students details which are entered to the program by the teacher. Then the teacher needs to be able to enter a specific student ID number and be able to add a score to the end of the record for this student. 
This is my code so far and works as it should. But it only allows the teacher to enter the students details and writes it to the text file.

```
    Dim studentID As String
    Dim studentname As String
    Dim classname As String

    Dim Filename As String
    Filename = “Students.txt”
    FileOpen(1, Filename, OpenMode.Append)

    Console.WriteLine("                                  Student Setup")
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.WriteLine()

    Console.Write("Student ID:  ")
    studentID = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("Student Name:  ")
    studentname = Console.ReadLine
    Console.WriteLine()
    Console.Write("Class  :  ")
    classname = Console.ReadLine
    WriteLine(1, studentID, studentname, classname)

    Console.WriteLine("Student successfully setup.")
```

Now I want to be able to allow the teacher to type in a students ID number and a score, and then write the score to the end of the specific line in the text file which begins with the students ID number.

An example of the text file will look like this:

"12345","Adam","A"

"67534","Alice","A"

"21456","Bob","A"

"98765","Charles","A"

"87654","Dennis","A"

Then if the teacher types in 21456 as the students ID number to add score to, and a score of 6 then it will add the number 6 to the end of this line, so that the line of the text file will now look like this:

"21456","Bob","A","6"

I have attempted to do this with the following code, which I got from another forum and tried to alter to do what I wanted to do:

```
    Dim score As Integer
    Dim studentIDenter As String
    Dim count As Integer

    Console.Write("Student ID to add score to: ")
    studentIDenter = Console.ReadLine
    Console.Write("Student score: ")
    score = Console.readline

    Dim lines() As String = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(Filename)
    For count = 0 To lines.Length - 1
        If lines(count).StartsWith(studentIDenter) Then
            lines(count) = studentID & studentname & classname & score
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Filename, lines)
        End If
    Next

    FileClose(1)
```

Comment: What is the problem with your "update" code?

Answer (score 0):

I assume the user is **NOT** entering quotes around the student number and score.

You need to add the quotes in your check for a match at the beginning of the line.  Additionally, you need to add a comma and quotes around the score when you add them to the end of the line.

Change to:

```
For count = 0 To lines.Length - 1
    If lines(count).StartsWith(Chr(34) & studentIDenter & Chr(34)) Then
        lines(count) = lines(count) & "," & Chr(34) & score & Chr(34)
        System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(Filename, lines)
        Exit For ' found the record, no need to keep looking
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created the following:

```
    Sub Main()
    Dim studentID As String
    Dim studentname As String
    Dim classname As String

    Dim addScoreSelection As String

    Dim inputSID As String

    Dim Filename As String
    Filename = “Students.txt”
    FileOpen(1, Filename, OpenMode.Append)

    Console.WriteLine("Add a Score? Y/N")
    addScoreSelection = Console.ReadLine.ToLower()

    If addScoreSelection = "Y".ToLower() Then
        FileClose(1)
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a student ID: ")
        inputSID = Console.ReadLine()
        AddScore(inputSID)
    ElseIf addScoreSelection = "N".ToLower() Then
        Console.WriteLine("Student Setup")
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine()

        Console.Write("Student ID:  ")
        studentID = Console.ReadLine
        Console.Write("Student Name:  ")
        studentname = Console.ReadLine
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.Write("Class  :  ")
        classname = Console.ReadLine
        WriteLine(1, studentID, studentname, classname)

        Console.WriteLine("Student successfully setup.")
    Else
        Console.WriteLine("No selection made. Exiting.")
        Process.GetCurrentProcess.Kill()
    End If


End Sub

Sub AddScore(ByVal ID As String)
    Dim Filename As String
    Filename = “Students.txt”

    Dim fileContent As String()

    Dim index As Integer = 0

    fileContent = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Filename)

    For Each line As String In fileContent
        If line.Contains(ID) Then
            fileContent(index) = fileContent(index) & ",""6""" 'Pass in a ByVal param for this
            Exit For
        End If
        index += 1
    Next

    IO.File.WriteAllLines(Filename, fileContent)
End Sub
```

I have added the sub routine AddScore that takes a student ID as a string param, I then use this parameter in a .Contains() to determine WHEN I have hit the line we are interested in in the text file.

I create a string array by reading all the text from the file

```
fileContent = IO.File.ReadAllLines(Filename)
```

I iterate through the array looking for the line in question, once the line is found I append the score to the end of the line (You will probably want to actually use a param here)

```
For Each line As String In fileContent
        If line.Contains(ID) Then
            fileContent(index) = fileContent(index) & ",""6""" 'Pass in a ByVal param for this
            Exit For
        End If
        index += 1
    Next
```

I then write the string array to the file

```
IO.File.WriteAllLines(Filename, fileContent)
```

This solves your issue I believe, but personally I am not happy with this. I don't like the idea of grabbing a whole lot of text and putting it into memory (imagine if we were reading a 5GB file...). The best solution in the long run would be to use the FileStream class to read/write it and find the line and append the text on said line.

Comment: Thanks very much, that does exactly what I hoped it would do! I will look into learning how to use a filestream class if it will be more efficient, as I have only been taught this way to use text files.

Comment: Also what do you mean in the comment: 'Pass in a ByVal param for this. Sorry if this is something basic but I have tried to change that line so that a score could be entered by the teacher but i couldnt get it to work?

Comment: Np, mark as answered if this solves the problem.  When I say Param I am saying add something like "ByVal Score as string" to the AddScore sub rotuine, that way you can take input for a score and append it to the end of the line (as you can see I just hard coded a value, 6)